# Javascript equivalent of visual foxpro gomonth()

Tags: javascript, visual-foxpro

I'm tasked with writing a web portal for a legacy application that was written in Visual Foxpro. I have to validate a pregnancy due date. The rule is that it can't be more than 9 months from the current date. I've already tried to argue that this is too vague and that it needs to be in days or weeks, but I was told that I have to mimic the legacy software.

Here's what the code in VSP is doing:

```
maxValueForDueDate = GOMONTH(DATE() , 9)
```

According to [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kfhds4cz%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) `GOMONTH()` handles edge cases as follows:

```
SET CENTURY ON
STORE GOMONTH({^1998-02-16}, 5) TO gdDeadLine

CLEAR
? gdDeadLine  && Displays 07/16/1998
? GOMONTH({^1998-12-31}, 2)  && Displays 02/28/1999
? GOMONTH({^1998-12-31}, -2)  && Displays 10/31/1998
```

As you can see adding 2 months to December 31st does not result in March 2nd, unfortunately that's exactly what the following javascript does:

```js
var dDate = new Date('1998-12-31');
dDate.setMonth(dDate.getMonth() + 2);
alert(dDate.toDateString()); // results in - Tue Mar 02 1999
```

Does anyone have a javascript function handy that they've written for this scenario? I've googled around, but haven't found what I need. I'm limited in my third-party usage to JQuery.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add the number of *milliseconds* (or seconds or hours or days) in 2 "full months" (that is, 30 days x 24 hours). The idea is that the entire date is shifted, and *not* just the single [month] component. [For example](http://jsfiddle.net/Xf538/1/):

```
var a = new Date('1998-12-31')
var ms_in_month = 30 * (24 * 60 * 60) * 1000
var b_ticks = (+a) + 2 * ms_in_month
var b = new Date(b_ticks)
alert(b) // Sun Feb 28 1999 16:00:00 GMT-0800 (Pacific Standard Time)
```

The `(+a)` coerces the Date to a number which results in the *number of milliseconds* since epoch. (This could also be written as [a.milliseconds](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date)). Then [`new Date(millis_since_epoch)`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date) does the reverse and creates a Date from the epoch offset.

**Disclaimer:** I am not sure what the *exact* rules for [`GOMONTH`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kfhds4cz%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) are
, and it might use the "30.5 days in a month heuristic" (365/12 = 30.41) or another variation. I *suspect* it does not account for the month durations (the documentation does state that "-1 [month] means -31 *days*") or leap years ..

Comment: I'm not sure why this works but it does, so thank you. So 30 days times 2 months averages out the days in a month?

Comment: @Nathan 30.5 days-per-month would be a better average over a year. Roughly. I am not sure what VFP uses though. If using non-whole-days (or caring about leap seconds) then the starting time should be biased to "mid day" to account for minor inacurracies.

Answer (score 0):

You can look at the open source javascript date library [Datejs](http://code.google.com/p/datejs/)

If you cannot add this file, you can at least look at the code to see how the edge cases are handled.